# iPod Touch WiFi Problems

Tags: troubleshooting, wireless-networking, ipod-touch

I am having major problems with my iPod Touch. The story so far...

I had it connected to my Netgear Router using WEP encryption which worked fine. I had to do some maintenance of my PC which to cut a long story lead me to step up the encryption of the router to WPA2. This wasn't a problem and my Laptop reconnected fine. However my iTouch didn't. I reset the network connection and it finds my network SSID however when I enter my password it tells me "Cannot join the network "

I get no IP address/subnet/dns entry in the DHCP section and all walkthroughs I have read simply state that  you need to reset the network connection in the iPod Touch .... which doesn't work for me.

I am banging my head against brick wall and I even tried disabling the wireless encryption totally but without any joy??

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a common problem (or at least it was in 2008) - see [this thread](http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=34648).

One solution mentioned here is:

> under your router settings make sure the encryption algorithm is TKIP.

I've found the same problem on [another forum](http://forums.cnet.com/5208-10152_102-0.html?threadID=314744). In this case the solution was:

> I changed a setting on the Trendnet so that it is using AES and the Preshared Key and that is now working. I sent an audio clip of my conversation with Apple support to the buzz email.

Comment: Getting WPA2 working on the router would be ideal as WEP is not secure and should not be used. Looks like ChrisF has the solution.

Comment: Did either option work? If so which one? I'm experiencing similar issues with the device claiming a full strength encrypted connection but not pulling down any DHCP settings properly.