# iPod wifi signal strength issue

Tags: troubleshooting, wireless-networking, ipod-touch

In follow up to my question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/75937/ipod-touch-wifi-problems), I am now having issues with the signal strenth of the wifi on my iPod touch. If I stand about a metre away from the router it connects fine. Move away and it drops the connection. The router is currently set up to use b and g and channel 11 and is a netgear wgr616 vr 7 and my laptop/psp connect no problem at all

Has anyone else had this issue??

EDIT: To respond to one of the comments The I-POD is not Jail broken

Comment: Is it a 1st generation ipod touch?

Comment: it is 1st generation

Comment: tried a reboot?

Comment: yes, rebooted the ipod, reset network connections and rebootecd the router

Comment: Have you tried changing the channel on the router?

Comment: yip tried b only and g only.....without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal: Double check the signals of other routers at the place where you drop the connection.

In my house I had a good connection while sitting, but standing up made me receive a signal from my neighbor through the window (which was not getting through the brick below the window), which made me lose the connection (sometimes). Once I monitored the signals and channels of other routers (using an apple laptop, about this computer -> more information -> Airport) in different places in the house I could find a good channel distribution. Please be also aware that line-of-sight is the only guarantee for a good connection. Walls, computers, CDs they all make strange things with your signal.

Answer (score 1):

Is your iPod jailbroken. I have had wifi issues before after jailbreaking my Touch. To resolve I had to restore to a approved firmware and then redo the jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be naive, but did you on some protective casing on the iPod touch?

Please note that the WiFi antenna of the iPod touch is being covered by a piece of black plastic at the back side of the touch, make sure it isn't block by anything.

Also, how about you try to connect your touch's WiFi in some other places?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do to troubleshoot this.

A. Try connecting wirelessly to another network at work or at the coffee shop or library.  If all is good, then start tweaking your router settings.

If the problem persists,

B. Restore your iPod via iTunes.  Does this solve the problem?  If so it may be an app or a combination of apps causing your problem.

If neither option works, you may have a faulty component or your son (not you obviously) may have dropped it on the tile floor.  The symptoms sound awfully similar to the time my iBook had a loose antenna connection to the airport card.  No antenna = very weak wireless reception.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the channel on the router? A lot of people know that 6 is terribly congested, so they set theirs to 1 and 11. This makes 1 and 11 almost as bad as 6 has been as far as interference.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your router manually and making sure the antennae aren't pointing away from your ipod. This was a source of my issues with my Ipod.